# How to instruct LoadFromText() to evaluate formulas?

Tags: .net, excel, epplus

I'm loading CSV data into Excel using EPPlus:

```
var csvFormat = new ExcelTextFormat() { Delimiter = ',', TextQualifier = '"', Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture };
sheet.Cells["A3"].LoadFromText(csvData, csvFormat, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium2, FirstRowIsHeader: true);
```

My `csvData` looks like this:

```
"A","B",TRUE,"=SomeExcelFormula"
"C","D",FALSE,"=SomeOtherExcelFormula"
```

After saving the package with EPPlus and opening the resulting document in Microsoft Excel neither the boolean values nor the formulas are evaluated automatically. I have to manually press `F2, ENTER` to evaluate the cell. This is unacceptable as I have a report with more than 80K lines.

How to instruct EPPlus to do this evaluation automatically? Neither specifying data type `Number` in `ExcelTextFormat`'s `DataTypes` property nor calling `sheet.Calculate()` did the job.

Please help :-)